# How to check if a column contains a substring of string in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if a column in my database contains words similar to my sample string.
The opposite of

`select * from myTable where name like '%words%';`

so that if I have record with `name=word` I could retrieve it. With sample above I can only get result where `words` is a sub string of name column in myTable, therefore I cant get `word`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just flip the two terms in your `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE 'words' LIKE CONCAT('%',name,'%')
```

I believe that `LOCATE()` and `INSTR()` may work here too which looks nicer since there isn't a need for concatenating the search term/substring.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE INSTR('words', name) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How is this `CONCAT('%',name,'%')` working? Is there a link you could forward me to?

Comment: It's merely tossing the wild cards around each `name` and searching that. It's exactly the same as your example but instead of saying `Where this "name" column is like this string` we are saying `Where this string is like this name column`. Not sure if there is documentation since it's just the `LIKE` operator doing its thing.